# What are these "pie" things in the Wikipedia picture of Ali slaying Jinn?

Tags: jinn, ali

In this picture the Jinn appear to be throwing pie at Ali. What are these things and why are they throwing them?

[image: Imam Ali and the Jinn (public domain)]

This image is used on the Wikipedia page [Jinn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jinn).  The description given is:

> Imam Ali Conquers Jinn Unknown artist Ahsan-ol-Kobar 1568 Golestan Palace From www.ir-tmca.com/exhibition/negargari/work6.htm

but this link gives a 404 Not Found error.

Comment: This is about a tradition where Ali was sent by the Prophet to annihilate Jinns who had settled in a valley to intercept and terrify Muslims. But  as for those pies they look like stones to me!

Comment: I guess the artist was just coming off of a fast.

Comment: Wikipedia is not a reliable source. It can be edited by anyone at any time. This means that any information it contains at any particular time could be vandalism, a work in progress, or just plain wrong. Edits on Wikipedia that are in error may eventually be fixed. However, because Wikipedia is a volunteer run project, it cannot monitor every contribution all of the time. There are many errors that remain unnoticed for days, weeks, months, or even years. Therefore, Wikipedia should not be considered a definitive source in and of itself.